# Put ArrayList into param JsonObject

Tags: java, android, android-volley

i must do i request with Volley Framework. This is a POST request with JSONObject.

I must pass one string and one JSONArray..but how i can?

I start with this:

```
 private String mUrl;
    private ArrayList<String> mUrlDove;

  HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("url", mUrl);
            params.put("urlDove", mUrlDove); ---> Wrong because mUrlDove is not a String


            mUrl = app.getInstance().getmUrlRestWS() + getString(R.string.path);

            JsonObjectRequest mRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                    mUrl, new JSONObject(params),
                    createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                    createMyReqErrorListener()) {
                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    return app.getInstance().createBasicAuthHeader();
                }
            };
```

If i try with Browser i must set this:

```
{
  "url": "www.secret.com",
  "urlDove" : [ "www.google.com","www.yahoo.com"]
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to make a JSON Array first and then store that

```
private String mUrl;
private ArrayList<String> mUrlDove;

HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
        params.put("url", mUrl);
        JSONArray jsArray = new JSONArray(mUrlDove);
        params.put("urlDove", jsArray.toString()); 

        mUrl = app.getInstance().getmUrlRestWS() + getString(R.string.path);

        JsonObjectRequest mRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                mUrl, new JSONObject(params),
                createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                createMyReqErrorListener()) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return app.getInstance().createBasicAuthHeader();
            }
        };
```

Comment: com.android.volley.ParseError: org.json.JSONException: Value Created of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject

Comment: i need help here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422727/how-to-send-json-array-as-post-request-in-volley

Answer (score 5):

try passing JSONObject instead of hashmap

```
JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
params.put("url", "www.secret.com");

JSONArray urlDove = new JSONArray();
urlDove.put("www.google.com");
urlDove.put("www.yahoo.com");

params.put("urlDove", urlDove);


JsonObjectRequest mRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(
                mUrl, params,
                createMyReqSuccessListener(),
                createMyReqErrorListener()) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                return app.getInstance().createBasicAuthHeader();
            }
        };
```

for reference in parsing json https://stackoverflow.com/a/17810270/4810752

Answer (score 2):

JSONObject can take in Java Objects, try using

```
Map<String,Object>
```

something like this:

```
    String mUrl;  //initialized somewhere else
    ArrayList<String> mUrlDove;  //initialized somewhere else

    Map<String, Object> jsonParams = new HashMap<>();
    jsonParams.put("url", mUrl);
    jsonParams.put("urlDove", mUrlDove);

    JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, new JSONObject(jsonParams),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>()
            {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response)
                {
                    Log.d("Volley Response: ", response.toString()); 
                    //do the other stuff you need...
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error)
                {
                    if (null != error.networkResponse)
                    {
                        Log.d(" Volley Error Code: ", "" + error.networkResponse.statusCode);
                       //probably throw an Exception or some MessageEvent
                    }
                }
            });

    requestQueue.add(request);
```

this works for me with complex objects like

```
 Map<String,<List<Map<String,Object>>>
```

with the most inner objects being Strings and Integers, and the List being initialized as a new ArrayList.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: can you help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422727/how-to-send-json-array-as-post-request-in-volley

Comment: @chris still relevant?